# Android multicolumn ListView

Tags: android, listview

My requirement is : When I click the list row , it need to go other activity. When I run this code, I got **NullPointerException** ; (I marked error place in comments)

This is my code:

```
ArrayList<Object> routeList = getWmRoute();
ArrayList<String> routhPath = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> alist=new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();

for(int i = 0; i<routeList.size();i++){
    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    map.put("RetailerCode", ((WMRoute) routeList.get(i)).getDescription());
    map.put("RetailerName", ((WMRoute) routeList.get(i)).getBusinessUnit());
    alist.add(map);
    }

ListView list=getListView();
sd = new SimpleAdapter(this,alist,R.layout.retalier_rows,new String[]{"RetailerCode","RetailerName"},new int[]{R.id.retailerCode,R.id.retailerName});
list.setAdapter(sd);
list.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
list.setSelected(true);
list.setSelection(0);
list.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
list.setItemsCanFocus(true);
list.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
list.setItemChecked(positions,true);
keyword = ((WMRoute) routeList.get(0)).getBusinessUnit(); // here Problem 1 place
//keyword = (String) list.getItemAtPosition(0); // here Problem 1 place
```

This is my listener part:

```
 @Override


  protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
        Object o = this.getListAdapter().getItem(position); //java.lang.NullPointerException -  problem here 2nd place
        keyword = o.toString(); // have to get first column value
        positions = position;
        if(position != 0 ){
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            Intent showContent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),RetailerOptionActivity.class);
            int postion = position;
            String aString = Integer.toString(postion);
            bundle.putString("positon", aString);
             startActivity(showContent);

        }
    }
```

When I click "OK" from menu option , I am setting parameters;

```
  @Override
  public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case 0:
            Intent showContent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),RetailerOptionActivity.class);
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString("RetailerName", keyword);
            showContent.putExtras(bundle);
             startActivity(showContent);
            return true;
        case 1:
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
```

This is my another activity:

```
Bundle bundle = this.getIntent().getExtras();
String RetailerName = bundle.getString("RetailerName");

setTitle(RetailerName + " - Retailer Option"); // want to get the parameter & set the title name
```

I have to set the title name , which is picked from previous list option clicked(selected first column name) .

Please help me..

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you post the error message? also you may want to reformat the question, its unclear what the actual question is .. just seems like you pasted code on the screen and thats it. what are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your onListItemClick() event, instead of using `this.getListAdapter().getItem(position)` to get the value of the first column in the item, you should use the `View v`, given to you as an argument to the event, to get the view that represents the first column. For example, if the first column is a textview, you should do the following:

```
TextView tv = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.firstColumnTextView);
keyword = tv.getText();
```